# How to check current emacs window position relative to other windows

Tags: emacs

I am using `S-<up>` and `S-<down>` to run (enlarge-window) and (shrink-window), respectively.

I would like these keys to be sensitive to the position of the current window relative to others. If my frame is split horizontally into two windows, and the current window is the top one, then I would like `S-<up>` to run (shrink-window) instead of (enlarge-window).

How do I check the position of the current window relative to the others?

Comment: I guess we need some information about the window manager. Also, you really should get a tilling window manager to get all those things out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the function `(window-edges)`. It returns a list of the window's coordinates. Just compare the y-axis value with the other visible windows.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, this is precisely what someone else has done here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowResize#toc2  Not sure why the heading is 'Resizing in big leaps' since the code does nothing with prefix arguments. But it does solve my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(window-tree)`. It will return not only the size of windows, but also their position , as a tree (in emacs' internals the windows of a frame are kept into a tree strucutre).